# Quirky accordion in nested tabs

Tags: jquery

I have nested tabs containing an accordion which isn't working properly.

Anybody know why? The headers behave as expected but none of the content is displayed.

http://jsfiddle.net/1Lxv4ob2/

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({ show: 'fade', hide: 'fade' });
    $("#tabs2").tabs({ show: 'fade', hide: 'fade' });
});
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Comment: The contents there but you need to scroll to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the order you initiate the tabs and accordion:

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion();

    $("#tabs").tabs({ show: 'fade', hide: 'fade' });
    $("#tabs2").tabs({ show: 'fade', hide: 'fade' });
});
```

If you set up your tabs first, the accordion will be hidden so jquery can't calculate the height of the accordion content so will give it a height of zero

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lxv4ob2/5/)

Comment: That explains why you could scroll to see the content. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use css to add a min height to the divs of your content

```
min-height:100px;
```

This worked for me.